# "Attribute hash", what's that?

Tags: javascript

I am reading [the annotated source code of backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-28) and it mentions "attribute hash". What is that?

> Set a hash of model attributes on the object, firing "change" unless you choose to silence it.

My understanding is it is an object, array, etc, or does hash refers to any format in particular?

Comment: Please add a link to or quote the part of the documentation. Without context, we cannot help much.

Comment: At what point did you think I know what document of some API in JavaScript you're talking about?

Comment: Ok. I thought it was a general term.

Comment: You didn't even know what it means.

Comment: @Tomalak..That's why I asked, and your answer doesn't help anyone at all

Comment: @William: You didn't know what it means, so why would you assume what sort of term it is, is what I meant. And I think you'll find my answer very helpful actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object, really:

```
var attributes = {
    option1: 'on',
    option2: 'off',
    option3: true,
    option4: 145
};

alert(attributes.option1); // on
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp, as this page notes: 

"Objects written as name value pairs (lastName: "Doe") is similar to:

Associative arrays in PHP.
Hash tables, hash maps or hashes in C, C++, C#, Java, Perl, and Ruby.
Dictionaries in Python.". I guess we could say that a hash of attributes is the same as saying a "set" of attributes. Emphasis on "set" in that they must be unique.

Comment: Maybe he uses "hash" instead of "set" to avoid having to say 'Set a "set" of attributes (one or many) on the model.' :)

Comment: @PhilipMurphy: He uses “hash” because it’s correct; “set” usually refers to unique values, not unique keys and arbitrary values.

Comment: '@false': You're right. On a separate note, it's tricky to find anything directly on the notion of a hash of attributes on the web. This phrase appears to have been coined by backbone. js.

Comment: @PhilipMurphy: http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/AttributeHash.pm

Comment: That website appears to be offline. Getting a 504 Gateway Time-out.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of all the instances of the term "hash" in that backbone.js documentation, I'd suggest that the author has used it to refer to a data container, representing mapping of "indexes" or "handles" to arbitrary property types.

This could be considered an implementation of [the more general "hash" concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), though I'd have to study the code properly to be sure that it fits.

To be honest, where he's written "hash", I'd just read "mapping" — or, since we're talking Javascript, even just "*object*".

Answer (score 0):

hash, if I'm thinking of what you're thinking of, refers to everything from `#` on in the href attribute of an element with the href property. It is a String.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you refer to

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/JPq7B/

```
var hash = new Array();
hash['first']  = 1;
hash['second'] = 2;
hash['third']  = 3;

alert(hash['first']);

//output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash can mean a huge number of things.

A lot of ex-PERL guys use it to mean "dictionary" (or "map" or ["associative array"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)), for the [wholly inadequate reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) that dictionaries are often implemented with [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and that's what I think it's being used to mean here.

It can also mean the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_algorithm) used to produce numbers for hash tables, it can mean the number produced by that algorithm; as a verb it means to apply the algorithm.

It also means the # character (the shift of 3 on American keyboards); used with URLs, it means that character plus everything to its right.  Since displaying a URL with a non-empty "hash" in that sense will make the browser try to scroll so that the first element with that ID is at the top, the ID itself is sometimes referred to as the hash.

In some places, hash is a kind of food, a mixture of ground beef and minced potatoes, a sort of very bland chili.

Finally, and most appropriately, it's slang word meaning "mess" or "catastrophe", as in "Don't make a hash of things."